# Group elements as powers

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, cryptography

I am reading [*Undeniable Signatures*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/0-387-34805-0_20.pdf) by Chaum and Antwerpen. On page 2,

> Consider using the group of known prime order $p$: All values transmitted between the participants are elements of this group, the multiplicatively denoted group operation is easily computed by all participants, ...

> A suitable group of prime order $p$ and a primitive element $g$ are initially established and made public for use by a set of signers. Consider a particular signer S having a private key $x$ and a corresponding public key $g^{x}$. A message $m (\neq 1)$ is signed by S to form signature $z$, which should be equal to $m^{x}$. ... The initial challenge is of the form $z^{a}(g^{x})^{b}$, where verifier V chooses $a$ and $b$ independently and uniformly from the group elements.

Here, where is $x$ in? Is it an element in the group? What does $g^{x}$ mean? Is $m$ also an element in the group? What does $z^{a}$ mean? The exponent is not an integer so I am not sure what the expression mean. Thank you.

Comment: "The exponent is not an integer" - Why not?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Because $a$ is an element from the group.

Comment: I think that, despite what it says, $a$ and $b$ (and $x$) are meant to be positive integers. $m$ is meant to be a group element.

Comment: The group you're picking $a,b,x$ from is $\left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$.   That is, they're basically just integers that aren't multiples of $p$.

Comment: So we just treat the group elements as $\{0,1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$. Then we can use $a,b,x$ like integers. Thanks!